# Could not fetch elements from a list in R. As one element contains multiple elements

Tags: r, dataframe

My list (`sector_region`) contains 2 elements. In those 2 elements there are multiple elements. How can I fetch these elements?

Following is my piece of code.

```
sector_region = unique(universe_database[, c("Region", "Sector")])
```

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible? See this post for help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Try `lapply(sector_region, function(x) unique(x[, c("Region", "Sector")]))`

Comment: lapply is giving incorrect number of dimensions. Dont know the reason behind it.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: Let's say :

employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope','John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope','John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope','John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')

salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800,21000, 23400, 26800,21000, 23400, 26800,21000, 23400, 26800)

universe_database <- data.frame(employee, salary,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

sector_region = unique(universe_database[,c("employee","salary")])


Now sector_region is a list. If I do sector_region[1] I will get a list of elements. How can I get single element like 'John Doe' ?

Comment: Add your code to your post. Do not put it in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quote your comment below:

> Let's say : employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope','John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope','John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope','John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope') salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800,21000, 23400, 26800,21000, 23400, 26800,21000, 23400, 26800) universe_database <- data.frame(employee, salary,stringsAsFactors=FALSE) sector_region = unique(universe_database[,c("employee","salary")]) Now sector_region is a list. If I do sector_region[1] I will get a list of elements. How can I get single element like 'John Doe'?

First of all, `sector_region` is a **data frame**, not a list. You can confirm that with `class(sector_region)`. By the way, your code is equivalent to `sector_region = unique(universe_database)` since you only have two columns for `universe_database`.

To retrieve "John Doe" here, simply execute `sector_region$employee[1]` or `sector_region[1, 1]`.

A more general solution would be `sector_region$employee[sector_region$employee %in% "John Doe"]`. Or, if you want to keep the returned values in a data frame, do `subset(sector_region, employee %in% "John Doe", select = employee)`.

Comment: Thanks "sector_region$employee[1] " helped me out.